# Invoke click through code in Webview

Tags: java, javascript, android

my name is Dan and I am trying to invoke a click on a HTML element through code in my Android application. If I try to click it through pure Javascript the result won't be the same as it is when the user clicks it.

So, how to press elements from a Webview component through Java code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String link) {

          return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
      }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but how do I use this code to invoke a click?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. no Idea how to invoke a click :S